# How do I make or setup a mailing list?

Tags: bulk-email, mailing-list

I know I could program it myself, but maybe there is a simple (that's the keyword) package.

I like to add a box, snippet, form or page to my site for users to input their email address. Then I'd like it to automatically send email saying you have successfully subscribe. I'd want an unsubscribe link and I would be using SMTP on Google apps.

I would like to send email with HTML, so I can have a [simple sentence with a complex link such as this](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?answer=55578).

I don't know if I'll get marked as spam if I try to send everyone an email at once.  I'd like the software to manage it. Also, I'd like to get the emails in a simple format like CSV.

Is there a simple app that does this? if not i can write a simple form which does a simple insert (or delete when unsubscribing) and write a 200-300 line app to send my emails out for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an existing newsletter service such as [MailChimp.](http://mailchimp.com)

Not only is it free for up to 2,000 subscribers (and 12,000 messages a month), but they offer [sign up forms](http://blog.mailchimp.com/customizing-email-signup-forms-in-mailchimp/), [click tracking](http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/how-do-i-track-clicks-and-opens/), [autoresponders](http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/how-do-i-create-an-autoresponder), [unsubscribe links](http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/how-do-i-place-my-unsub-unsubscribe-tag-in-my-html-version), increased chance of delivery over hacked-together DIY solutions, and much more.

There's little reason to create your own email newsletter solution when someone's already solved the hard problems for you; you could write and run your campaigns straight away instead.

Comment: I hate the idea of paying $30 a month if i happen to shoot up from 1700 to 2001 subscribers. It says "No credit card required". If i get 2001 subscribers, may i still download the list and terminate the service? Or will i not have access to my subscribers until i upgrade?

Comment: @acidzombie24 You'd have to ask them that; I couldn't find that info on their Support pages. They have a link to live support on their [support page](http://kb.mailchimp.com/). You could also use their Pay & Go plan. No limit to the number of subscribers; you just pay per email sent by topping up with credit bundles.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer however i dont think i'll be sending out emails until after 2k members. If all i need for the moment is collection and sending a welcome email i can spend 10mins programming it myself.

Comment: @acidzombie24 If you'd like to offer more than just welcome emails and want a self-hosted solution, check out [PHPList.](http://www.phplist.com/)